# How to pull the latest changes to my current working branch in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Suppose I'm in branch 'abc-test'

```
git pull origin master
```

Does this merges master branch with my current Branch('abc-test') or do I need to run more commands?

Comment: Pull does a fetch and then a merge (into the _current_ branch). I recommend researching the topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `git pull origin master` will pull changes from the origin remote, master branch and merge them to the local checked-out `abc-test` branch
2. may be you will get conflicts then you have to resolve the conflict and commit the change `git commit -m"Your commit Message"`
3. If no conflict then skip step 2 go to step 4
4. then you have to push the change `git push`

Comment: suppose i've a conflict in a file acb.php, what is the best way to resolve the conflict.
is there any tool for that... or is there any information about conflict where it occurs...?

Comment: I am using [p4merge](https://www.perforce.com/products/helix-core-apps/merge-diff-tool-p4merge)

Answer (score 5):

### tl;dr:

run `git fetch` to fetch latest changes, then run `git rebase master` to update your branch to the latest changes in master.

---

Now, to answer your question: yes, `git pull origin master` does merge them.

However, what you probably want is to apply the commits from master to your branch and then reapply yours on top of them.

That's known as a rebase. The git-rebase manual (which you can access straight from the terminal with `git rebase --help` is full of helpful diagrams to help you understand what the commit graph looks like.

This is one of them:

```
Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "topic":
             A---B---C topic
            /
       D---E---F---G master

From this point, the result of the following command:

       git rebase master

would be:

                     A'--B'--C' topic
                    /
       D---E---F---G master
```

If you use `git pull`, your graph is going to get really messed up really quickly. Especially if you start using it to update local branches with new commits from a remote repo, because then you'd be creating merge commits from a branch to itself, which is unnecessary and often misleading.

Most of these situations can be avoid by running `git pull --rebase` or simply `git pull -r` instead of git pull.

Tip: use `git log --oneline --graph` as frequently as you can so you can get used to your repos' graph and what are the effects of each git command on it.

Note: Be careful when rebasing too deeply. Read the git-rebase manual.